# What is the limit on number of paramaters passed in a SQL UDF?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to transform the information I am pulling into Snowflake with a variant table, and creating a new table with the calculated data that I need.

For example I am pulling in this information

Data col:

[image]

and I want to calculate to a table like this as the output:

TEAM |Min_speed|Max_speed|Median_speed|Mean_speed|Average_speed|current_date

I [read here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009YB4YmSAL/is-it-possible-to-nest-multiple-functions-inside-of-a-function-and-pass-all-the-parameters-required) that you need to separate javascript and SQL UDFs, but could not find any limitation on the number of parameters that I could pass into a UDF.

With python, I can transform this information, but I want the table to insert it overtime - I am exploring Lamdas in my s3 stage, but for now I need to focus on the udf to call on the load of new data into the table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SPEED_BY_GAME_DAY (team_id, sprint_speed)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS '
    INSERT INTO new_table VALUES(SELECT team_id, MIN(sprint_speed) as Min_speed, MAX(sprint_speed) as AVG(sprint_speed_) as AVG_speed, CURRENT_DATE() 
    FROM 
      tablename
    WHERE 
      CURRENT_DATE() = TODAY()
    GROUP BY team_id; )
';
```

Is this the right direction?

Comment: Why don't you run and try first? As per snowflake documentation, there is no limit of parameters while creating UDFs. In generals, UDFs will take a handful of parameters. A developer will not pass 15-20 params to a UDFs, a very unlikely case. On the other side, you have mixed a lot of questions together. Do you have issues with stored procedure approach or UDF param limitations?

Comment: All the examples of UDFs did not have more than a few parameters. I was looking for an option to automate a few statistics from a few different tables with similar data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is available as a Variant type then we can directly flatten the data to meet the objective and no need to go through UDF code.

For testing I have created a table with variant column and added records for team_id and sprint_speed. These records were then flattened to get their values which were used to insert the records in the new_table.

```
create or replace table team_table1 (col1 variant)


create or replace table team_table2 
(team_id number, 
 min_sprint number (3,1), 
 max_sprint number (3,1),
 avg_sprint number (3,1),
 current_date date)

insert into team_table1
select parse_json(column1) as col1
from values 
( '
{
"team statistics": 
{
"stats": [
{
"team_Id": "109",
"sprint_Speed": "30.8"
}
]
}
}') as valinsert 

insert into team_table1
select parse_json(column1) as col1
from values 
( '
{
"team statistics": 
{
"stats": [
{
"team_Id": "120",
"sprint_Speed": "30.4"
}
]
}
}') as valinsert 

insert into team_table1
select parse_json(column1) as col1
from values 
( '
{
"team statistics": 
{
"stats": [
{
"team_Id": "142",
"sprint_Speed": "30.3"
}
]
}
}') as valinsert 




insert into team_table2
with cte as (
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT
SEQ,
VALUE['team_Id']::number AS team_Id,
VALUE['sprint_Speed']::number(3,1) AS sprint_speed
from team_table1,
LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => COL1['team statistics']['stats'])
ORDER BY SEQ, INDEX
) 
)

select 
team_Id,
MIN(sprint_speed), 
MAX(sprint_speed),
AVG(sprint_speed), 
CURRENT_DATE 
FROM cte  
GROUP BY team_id;

select * from team_Table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks like a theoretical exercise.

There is clearly a practical maximum somewhere, how can you retain oversight over hundreds of parameters?

If you need a ridiculous amount of parameters, you can structure them into a single parameter of the `VARIANT` type, which can be constructed with `OBJECT_CONSTRUCT()` and `ARRAY_CONSTRUCT()`.